# Dynamically created components cannot access parent properties

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyside, pyside2

In my python & qml project I have a page structure which is as follows

```
 Window
  |-myObject
  |-Loader
   |-homePage
    |-myComponent
```

Where MyComponent is a component which I dynamically create with the following Python code:

```
root = engine.rootObjects()[0].findChild(QObject, "HomePage")
componentFigure = QQmlComponent(engine)
componentFigure.loadUrl(QUrl("components/MyComponent.qml"))
instanceFigure = componentFigure.create()
instanceFigure.setParentItem(root)
```

Now I want to access myObject properties, from `HomePage` it works fine, from `myComponent` it doesn't work (**Cannot read *PropertyName* of undefined**)

Probably there is some problem in my component creation?

Root page code:

```
Window {
    Settings {
        id: appSettings
        property bool light: true
    }
    QtObject {
        id: myObject
        property color myColor: {appSettings.mySetting ? "#FFFFFF" : "#000000"}
    }
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Loader {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: Qt.resolvedUrl("pages/homePage.qml")
        }
    }
}
```

MyComponent code:

```
MyComponent{
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: myObject.myColor
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code so we can see how you are trying to make these references.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `myObject` is only going to be a visible identifier in your root component. It will not be visible from other components outside of that file. Only the properties of the top level QML element of a component are visible in the component scope hierarchy.

See this for more info: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-scope.html#component-scope

You will need to make sure these connections are setup in your code, something like this:

```
instanceFigure = componentFigure.create(qmlContext(root))
```

Note however that accessing components this way (by implicit access through parent component scopes) is not really recommended. It's better to pass object references down via explicit properties.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in my current configuration I can access the properties of myObject from other files without any problem, the problem is I can not access them from dynamically loaded components. Unfortunately the code you suggested doesn't change anything